# СSS как сделать такие ссылки?

Tags: css, link, border

Как c помощью СSS сделать такие ссылки? Нужно чтобы при наведении курсором они были оранжевыми с белыми символами, а без курсора с серыми с черными символами. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.link {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 25px 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 40px 0 40px;
  border-color: #ccc transparent transparent transparent;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: orange;
}

.link:hover:after {
  border-top-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
```